# Enthalpy of formation function of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water

Why is the enthalpy of formation a function of the temperature?
We can see in the dedicated tables (such as [JANAF](https://janaf.nist.gov/)),

[image: JANAF table H2O]

that the enthalpy of formation changes with temperature.

Doesn't the enthalpy of formation stay constant, while the sensible enthalpy of a species only changes with temperature?

Answer (score 4):

> Doesn't the enthalpy of formation stay constant, while the sensible
> enthalpy of a species only changes with temperature?

The temperatures in the table are the saturation temperatures (boiling points) of water corresponding to different saturation pressures (boiling pressures, not shown). For example, the saturation pressure associated with 373.15 K is one atmosphere.

The higher the pressure the higher the boiling point of water and the greater the amount of heat per unit mass needed to convert the liquid to a vapor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You said that the saturation pressure associated with 298.15 K is one atmosphere. Don't you means 373.15 K ?

Comment: @AeroThermo Yes. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The heats of formation reported in standard tables in references are at 298 K.  But from these values, and the molar heat capacities of the products and reactants, one can use [Hess' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hess%27s_law) to calculate the heats of formation of compounds at other temperatures.